# asking for solution for move site from one server to another server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint Server Enterprise 2007 with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have a site collection which is using 3 types of sites publishing portal/wiki/blog. I want to move the template (e.g. master pages) and data from one server to another. Server domain names and IP address are different.

What is the suggested way to do this task?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Content Deployment Wizard:

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/12/introducing-sharepoint-content.html
http://www.codeplex.com/SPDeploymentWizard

or, just use STSADM backup and restore operations:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263431.aspx